# django handle slowly when doing Stress Testing

Tags: django

i had built django server to handle some work.And when i sent 10000 requests to django,django will became slow after 4000th requests,it will report socket timeout randomly.And i take this one data to test it alone,it is ok.So,how can i fix this bug?

```
i have no idea to fix it

def handle(request) :
  sys.stderr.write( "[info]request come in {} \n".format(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name))

  ret_dict = dict()
  ret_str = ""
  if ("vid" in request.GET) and ("title" in request.GET):
    id = request.GET["id"]
    title = urllib.parse.unquote(request.GET["title"],encoding ='utf-8')
    title = request.GET["title"]

    req_video = dict()
    req_video["vid"] =  vid
    req_video["title"] = title
    tags = handle_function(req_video)
    ret_dict["vid"] = vid
    ret_dict["tags"] = tags
    ret_str = json.dumps(ret_dict)


  return HttpResponse(ret_str)
```

client codes:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            fields = line.split("\t")
            vid = fields[0]
            title = fields[1]
            page_params_mq = {'vid':vid,'title':title}
            try :
                    rec_mq_res = get_rec_mingqiang(server_ip_mq, server_port_mq, web_page_mq, page_params_mq)
            except:
                    print (line)
                    continue
            vid = rec_mq_res["vid"]
            tags = rec_mq_res["tags"]
            fo.write(vid+"\t"+tags+"\n")
```

cat test_data|python client.py, there are 10000 rows in test_data,and it send request sequentially,and will be hunt randomly after 4000.
django can handle these requests quickly

Comment: are you running django development server or is there any nginx or apache

Comment: runing django development server.It is strange that it will occur slowly randomly after start to send request to server

Comment: what's the point of stress testing the django `runserver`?  the django development server handles requests sequentially, cannot handle parallel requests, so probably after 4000 requests, your queue of requests is full and some requests have to get dropped (timeout). But what you're doing is pointless. the Django development server isn't made for this.

Comment: i have updated client codes.And clients using shell command to sent requests sequentially,not parallel.So how can i fix this issue.Is my logic code take much time?

Comment: I add time cost in code. If send requests one by one,it will cost 31s sometimes,but if i send this request alone,it cost only 60ms .Why it happed ?could u give some advices?@dirkgroten